# How to define a Jenkins String parameter based on the Choice parameter selected

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

I am trying to setup a job , which requires  the user to enter a input String on the Choice selected

I have seen various plugin, but all of them have the option of Choice parameters to be picked up from but not a string one

Scenario - Product ( abc, def , ghi , jkl)
If the product name is only **"def"** then the user need to enter the dependent revision number as a string parameter "12356" , if any other product is selected then user shouldnt have any option to enter the string parameter

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in Jenkins build with parameters page.
Parameters are loaded all at once, and cannot have logic that depends on the value of another one.

You have a few options, some easy ones are:

1. In JenkinsFile/Pipeline, once job has kicked off, evaluate value of the product param and if 'def' Prompt user for subsequent input
   https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/
2. Have the string field present as a param, but in the description note that it is only required when product == 'def' and otherwise ignore it regardless of value

Comment: Thank you, i know if there is no other option i was planning to go with option 2 as u listed, but i will try to evaluate option 1 as well.